# CONVERT function cannot convert string to DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string like this that I want to convert to a DATETIME value.
`DECLARE @eh NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2021-07-19 14:00:39.0000000'`

So this is what I tried:

```
DECLARE @eh NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2021-07-19 14:00:39.0000000'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @eh)
```

But it always returns this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I am not sure what is special about the format of my string value that is causing the issue.

I tried the code above and I am using SQL Server.

Comment: You're trying to convert the empty `@time` variable, not the string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh lol good catch !  OK I replaced it but now legitimately getting a conversion error

Comment: Fixed the question to account for the typo and reduced the code down closer to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIME2, @eh)) instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert the empty `@time` variable, not the string. Try `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @eh)` instead.

With the current text you'll get an error because the legacy `datetime` type doesn't have nanosecond precision. If you include only milliseconds, it will work.

```
DECLARE @eh NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2021-07-19 14:00:39.000';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @eh);
---
2021-07-19 14:00:39.000
```

If you use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` you can parse nanoseconds too:

```
DECLARE @eh NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2021-07-19 14:00:39.0000000'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, @eh)
---
2021-07-19 14:00:39.0000000
```

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't know about the nanoseconds difference. cool thanks